# UIAutomation through command line on a real device

Tags: ios, command-line, instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I know starting from `Xcode 4.2` it is possible to run `UIAutomation` scripts through command line. I've tried this and is working perfectly fine for me in simulator. I'd like to know how to get this run in an actual device.I searched and got the command for running on device as,

`instruments -w <device_id> -t /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate`

`application -e UIASCRIPT`

`script -e UIARESULTSPATH <results path>`

What exactly should I give in the *application*, is it the path to *ipa* or something else?

Advance Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give it the path to the `.ipa` file. It actualy only needs the *app name* so you can just pass in the app name.
 **Very Important :** The app needs to be installed on the device, Instruments *will not* install the app on the device, **it will only run a installed app on the device**

Comment: Could you elaborate more on "the path to the .ipa" file pls? What's the path about?

Comment: @WendyMunmunWang An IPA file is an iOS app. The path to the IPA is the location of the app (ex. `/Users/MyUser/Documents/App.ipa`).