# iOS: Deploy and run app on device through command-line without jailbreaking

Tags: ios, testing, deployment, build, automation

I'm looking for a way to automate dev-test cycles for iOS and most popular ways seemed to be jailbreak then ssh. This includes two steps:

1. Deploy my app using command line from Mac/PC to the device.
2. Run the app on the device from Mac/PC command line.

However, since iOS6 and iPhone5 the official jailbreaking had been flaky which made me want to find an alternative solution not based on jailbreak.

I've seen fruitstrap and [this post](http://pervasivecode.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/install-ios-app-ipa-file-without-xcode.html).

However, the former is no longer maintained and the latter seems to be far from official or stable. So here I am again, any idea is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run instruments on the command line to launch your app (and run your automated tests) in the simulator. From what I understand this works with a real device as well.

See this question for more information:

[UIAutomation through command line on a real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286850/uiautomation-through-command-line-on-a-real-device)

Comment: With IOS 10 and Xcode 8 UIAutomation has been just dropped, so you cannot start an app with the Automation.tracetemplate anymore. However one can run an app with just another tracetemplate such as the  Leaks.tracetemplate (given that you can user other methods for QA testing than the JS methods from UIAutomation)

Answer (score 3):

[ios-deploy](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy) from PhoneGap is a fork of fruitstrap, so it may be something worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

Bill's link answered the "build and run" part of my question.

I'll answer the deploy part: The only working method I found was to use the ruby gem transporter_chief.rb over an IPA app:

```
./transporter_chief.rb my.ipa
```

http://gamua.com/blog/2012/03/how-to-deploy-ios-apps-to-the-iphone-via-the-command-line/

Comment: transporter_chief uses fruitstrap underneath. For this readon ios-deploy is the best answer I think.