# How to launch releasable iOS app via command line?

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line

I have releasable iOS ipa file and I want to launch (mb and close) it via command line on real device.
I try to do it via idevicedebug, ios-deploy and appbuilder, but, how I understand, it require debugable app.

Now I have this error:

```
ERROR: failed to get the task for process XXX
```

It all real?

Comment: Would [the answers to this very related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579097/ios-deploy-and-run-app-on-device-through-command-line-without-jailbreaking) help you out?

Comment: these methods are not working with xcode8 and ios10 - [confirming answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579097/ios-deploy-and-run-app-on-device-through-command-line-without-jailbreaking#comment65684271_15582719)